# Prisma findUnique relation within relation of User

Tags: prisma, supabase

I have a database with the following schema Whereby User has lotInterests and within this table I want to select the Lot with a matching address.

What I have tried:

```
const foundLot = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
              email: "xyz@gmail.com"
            },
            include: {
              lotInterests: {
                include: { lot: true },
                    where: {
                      lot: {
                        address: "123 St, Find Me Town"
                      }
                    }
                  }
              }
            })
```

Which returns the User with an empty array for lotInterests. Maybe I am getting a match then but just not returning it yet?

Schema below:

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @unique @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  lotInterests  LotInterest[]
}

model LotInterest {
  id                String @default(cuid()) @id

  // Relation Fields
  userId       String?  
  lotId        String? 
  user         User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  lot          Lot?    @relation(fields: [lotId], references: [id])
  @@unique([userId, lotId])
  @@index([userId, role])
}

model Lot {
  id            String  @id @unique @default(cuid())
  zipCode       String
  address       String  @unique

  // Relation fields
  interest LotInterest[]
}
```

I am hoping for something like

```
{
  id: 'cljxsmdxw0094hkgkgn8urnrv',
  name: 'XYZ',
  email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  lotInterests: [
           lot: {
             address: 123 St, Find Me Town,
             metadata: etc..
                 }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution:-

```
const foundLot = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  },
  include: {
    lotInterests: {
      select: {
        lot: {
          where: {
            address: '123 St, Find Me Town',
          },
          select: { address: true },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

the output

```
{
  id: 'cljxsmdxw0094hkgkgn8urnrv',
  name: 'XYZ',
  email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  lotInterests: [
    {
      lot: {
        address: '123 St, Find Me Town',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

if you want all attribute of lot remove its select as following

```
const foundLot = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  },
  include: {
    lotInterests: {
      select: {
        lot: {
          where: {
            address: '123 St, Find Me Town',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

and the output will be

```
{
  id: 'cljxsmdxw0094hkgkgn8urnrv',
  name: 'XYZ',
  email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
  lotInterests: [
    {
      lot: {
        id: 'cljysoe910001imuvnut93n9j',
        zipCode: '',
        address: '123 St, Find Me Town',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when trying to retrieve all of Lot I get the error: 
Unknown arg `where` in include.lotInterests.include.lot.where for type Lot. Did you mean `select`? Available args:
type lot {

}

Comment: please write the code that causes this error

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot to connect user to the lot first before running this.. lol!
Correct answer was indeed what I first published. Thanks for your help!

```
const foundLot = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
              email: "xyz@gmail.com"
            },
            include: {
              lotInterests: {
                include: { lot: true },
                    where: {
                      lot: {
                        address: "123 St, Find Me Town"
                      }
                    }
                  }
              }
            })
```